# T-Shirt flash designer

Tags: flash

Anybody know what flash component is this site using : http://www.comboutique.asia/shop/design_your_own_t_shirt.html? It looks neat and feature rich.

I've tried http://www.harboarts.com/shirtdesigner/ but it doesn't really nice compared to the above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I check the sourcecode of this site, the only hint I can find is the comment <--TSM2--> which I would interpret as T-Shirt Manager 2. Googling this doesn't lead anywhere. To me it looks like a thing they would develop themselves anyways since it is the main asset of their business.

So maybe you should contact the developer of this site directly.

Comment: I've tried to view-source their code hoping to get some clues but it seems like they custom developed it, like you've said earlier. I doubt they will respond if I contact them since it is not an abligation for them to divulge their business secret. LOL

Thanks for responding.